# Accessing what I think is a JSON object

Tags: python, json

I am using a python library to retrieve some real time data. When I output the results, stored in a variable called "nearest" I get this:

```
{'distance': 0.032766888603455446,
 'station': {'id': 219,
             'installDate': 1279545900000L,
             'installed': True,
             'lat': 51.49016361,
             'locked': False,
             'long': -0.19039362,
             'name': u"Bramham Gardens, Earl's Court",
             'nbBikes': 7,
             'nbDocks': 29,
             'nbEmptyDocks': 21,
             'removalDate': None,
             'temporary': False,
             'terminalName': u'001183'}}
```

How do I access the information stored in `long` and `lat`?

I have tried

```
json.decode(nearest)  
json.parse(nearest)
```

and various other methods but to no avail.
I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'JSONDecoder' object is not callable
```

My aim is retrieve the values for 'lat 'long' and 'name' and store those in variables to be used elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Is `nearest` a string or a dict or something else? What does `print(type(nearest))` say?

Comment: Also, what is `json.decode`? I don't think that's a method in the `json` module.

Comment: @Kevin: the syntax is Python's. I'm betting `str`.

Comment: Please include **full tracebacks** at all times; your exception is intriguing, because if all you did was `import json` you'd *never get that error*. You are doing something funky here, and you'll need to show us how you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the items in the dictionary (JSON object) using the appropriate keys:

```
data = {'distance': 0.032766888603455446,
        'station': {'id': 219,
                    'installDate': 1279545900000L,
                    'installed': True,
                    'lat': 51.49016361,
                    'locked': False,
                    'long': -0.19039362,
                    'name': u"Bramham Gardens, Earl's Court",
                    'nbBikes': 7,
                    'nbDocks': 29,
                    'nbEmptyDocks': 21,
                    'removalDate': None,
                    'temporary': False,
                    'terminalName': u'001183'}}

latitude = data['station']['lat']
longitude = data['station']['long']

>>> print '({}, {})'.format(latitude, longitude)
(51.49016361, -0.19039362)
```

I have assumed here that you have already successfully parsed the JSON string into a Python dictionary with `json.loads()` or similar (or perhaps an API returned the dictionary to you?). As it stands, the JSON that you posted is not valid JSON due to the use of single quotes - it should be double quotes, and the value for `name` has a Python unicode prefix.

Comment: This does look like it would retrieve the data as desired... But only if `nearest` is a dict. If it's a string that just looks like a dict when you print it, you'll get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: There is also the issue with `TypeError: 'JSONDecoder' object is not callable`; we have no idea how the OP managed that.

Comment: Take a closer look at the OP's sample... the strings are single quoted and there is at least one string prefixed with `u`. Looks like a Python dictionary to me, and if OP has that, then it's simply a matter of accessing the values as presented in my answer.

Comment: @mhawke: unless it is still a string with a Python representation.. It certainly did not come from a `json.loads()` call because then **all** strings would be unicode values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  - yes, something is a fishy; the strings with `u` prefix have different quoting, so yep, might not be what I thought.

Comment: Both have correct quoting for Python literals; the first one contains a `'` so uses double quotes. Both are ASCII-safe, so this is not the `simplejson` library producing byte strings for ASCII-only JSON strings either, unless something changed and that only happens for keys now. Fishy.

Comment: Hi all thanks for your comments. I have started with the easiest one print(type(nearest)) returns <type 'dict'>

Comment: I got the object from an API using a third party library - I am using a library called boris and another called pprint
from boris import BikeChecker
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

Comment: thanks @mhawke - that appears to have done the trick! amazing :)